# MongoDB How to update fields in database manually?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a collection in Mongo. I need to update some fields manually. The document is long, it has 20 fields.

I need to see what is inside and rewrite it or don't change itd. And I need to do this document by document.

What I need

- take first document
- show value of all fields
- change manually the fields that needed update, keep the rest

record 1

id: 1

name: John

number: 6657383

city: Miami

position: driver

itd

record 2

id: 2

name: Kate

number: 66574444

city: NY

position: None

itd

I don't; want to make it like this:

update_one({name:John}, {set:...}}

update_one({name:Kate}, {set:...}}

Because in different  document i would like to change different fields, sometimes all fields should be changed. So I need to load what it is now in that document, see it and rewrite it and than update in mongo.

So I load first record:

id: 1

name: John -> change manually to "Robert"

number: 6657383

city: Miami -> "Change manually to NY

position: driver

itd

And the record is updated in mongo.

Answer (score 2):

you can use mongodb compass UI
https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass